# tool for plot transform matrix

Tags: html, matrix, plot, html5-canvas, transform

have tool for help me plot 3D transform matrix from image 
to html 5 canvas like this

```
max-width: intrinsic;
-moz-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1.5, 15em, 0);
-webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 250, 0);
-o-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 250, 0);
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 250, 0);
```